# How to access all arguments of a method in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, decorator

I have built a decorator to handle a certain error in a service of mine. I have achieved it like this:

```
interface MyServiceInterface {
    doBar(otherParam: number): string;

    doFoo(param1: string, param2: number): string;
}

class MyServiceClass implements MyServiceInterface {

    doFoo(param1: string, param2: number): string {
        throw new Error("I SHOULD BE CAUGHT");
    }

    doBar(otherParam: number): string {
        throw new Error("I SHOULD BE CAUGHT");
    }
}

class MyDecorator implements MyServiceInterface {
    constructor(private service: MyServiceInterface) {
    }

    public doFoo(param1: string, param2: number): string {
        try {
            return this.service.doFoo(param1, param2);
        } catch (e) {
            return "THIS SPECIAL CASE IS NOW RESOLVED";
        }
    }

    public doBar(otherParam: number): string {
        try {
            return this.service.doBar(otherParam);
        } catch (e) {
            return "THIS SPECIAL CASE IS NOW RESOLVED";
        }
    }
}

const instance = new MyDecorator(new MyServiceClass());

console.log([
    instance.doBar(1),
    instance.doFoo("biz", 2),
].join("\n"));
```

I dislike repeating myself in the decorator, and hence I want my catch block to be more dynamic. I want to pass through the function and all arguments into one function, as my error handling will be the same.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store a function as a variable and store your arguments inside an array. Then you can use [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like so:

```
class MyDecorator implements MyServiceInterface {
    constructor(private service: MyServiceInterface) {
    }

    public doFoo(param1: string, param2: number): string {
        const args = [param1, param2];

        return this.handleErrorCase(this.service.doFoo, args);
    }

    public doBar(otherParam: number): string {
        const args = [otherParam];

        return this.handleErrorCase(this.service.doBar, args);
    }

    private handleErrorCase<T>(fn: any, args: any[]): string {
        try {
            return fn.apply(this.service, args) as string;
        } catch (e) {
            return "THIS SPECIAL CASE IS NOW RESOLVED";
        }

    }
}
```